# Validating TEdit input, by comparing it with an integer value

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have developed an application that randomly creates two integers and then adds them. The sum of the two integers must be worked out by a user and input in TEdit. 
When I use if statement to validate the answer(in TEdt) I get an error.
the code snipped:

```
answer := int1+int2;
UserAnswer:=StrToInt(edtAnswer.Text);
if(UserAnswer=answer)then 
   lblRemark.Caption:= 'Correct Answer';
```

When run the application I get an a convertError  "Error...Not a valid integer".

Comment: It's some time since I last programmed in delphi, but from some small research I think it would be safe to consider that your string value from `edtAnswer.Text` has some whitespace which can lead to a convertError. Try to Trim the string value (removes leading/trailing-whitespace) before converting it into an integer value by using the trim function e.g ` UserAnswer := StrToInt(Trim(edtAnswer.Text));`. Also you should tell us your variable declaration and some values you entered into the textfield. This should make it alot easier for use to find the error.

Answer (score 3):

When `StrToInt` meets a string that cannot be converted to an integer, it raises an exception. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt) says:

> If `S` does not represent a valid number, `StrToInt` raises an `EConvertError` exception.

You can catch that exception.

```
try
  Value := StrToInt(Str);
except
  on EConvertError do
    // handle conversion error
end;
```

However, this is rather messy code. As a broad rule, exceptions should really be exceptional. They should not be part of the normal flow of your program. Another broad rule is that you should not handle exceptions. Let them propagate upwards to something that can handle them.

So, if we are breaking both of these rules, how can we do better? Well, by using [`TryStrToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt). This is a function that returns a `Boolean` to indicate whether or not the conversion succeeded. The code would then go like this:

```
if TryStrToInt(Str, Value) then
  // handle conversion success by using Value
else
  // handle conversion error
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Int1 and Int2 are 'reasonable' for a user (eg. positive only) you can also use

Value := StrToIntDef( Str, -1 {or other illegal value});

Makes the code slightly simpler, maybe.